# Qt. Method displayText() doesn't work if I defined paint() method in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt

This is my problem:

I have a delegate derived from QStyledItemDelegate, where I defined the methods

```
QWidget * createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem&option, const QModelIndex&index) const;
void setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex&index)const;
void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex&index) const;
QString displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const;
```

The last method -displayText()- let me format the output of the numbers in Spanish locale and it works fine.

But, after that I create another delegate from inheritance of the first delegate. In this class I only define the next methods:

```
void paint( QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
QSize sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
```

And the problem is that the columns where those delegate is working, doesn't show the numbers well formated like displayText() should be do.

In the same way, if I defined both of these methods (displayText() and paint()) int the same class, displayText() doesn't work.

Edit:

These are the implementations of the methods:

displayText() in the base class:

```
QString Delegado::displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const
{
    qDebug()<<"Valor: "<<value.toString()<<"locale - "<<locale;
    return locale.toString(value.toDouble(),'f',2);
}
```

paint() and sizeHint() in the derived class (I have try to implement these methods in the base class and the results are the same)

```
    void Delegado2::paint( QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(QColor(255,255,170));
        painter->setBrush(QColor(255,255,170));
        painter->drawRect(option.rect);
        painter->setPen(Qt::gray);
        painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(index.data().toDouble()));
        painter->restore();
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
    else
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}

    QSize Delegado2::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        return option.rect.size();
    }
```

Comment: Do you call parent class QStyledItemDelegate::paint() implementation from inside your implementation of paint?

Comment: Yes. Even if paint() and dispayText() methods are in the same class, displayText() doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide implementation of your paint() and displayText() method

Comment: I have edited the post for show the methods. Thx

Comment: As I wrote above, what happens if you call ```Delegado::paint(painter, option, index);``` even in case with index.valid() == true ?

Comment: It's curious. In that case I can see the numbers in both formats. I put a link to the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/4uDUrhb.jpg

Comment: well, and what will be showed if you will call ```QStyledItemDelegate::paint()``` instead ```Delegado::paint(painter, option, index);``` as I asked initially? :)

Comment: I get the same result. I have edit the previouse code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. It works but I don't know if that way is the correct way.
First, I define the displayText() method in the Delegado (derived from QStyledItemDelegate). This is my base class and it let me get the numbers in my locale format.

After thar, in Delegado2 (derived from Delegado) I defined paint() and sizeHint() methods. 
paint() use displayText() method for draw the text, as below:

```
painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignCenter|Qt::AlignRight, displayText(index.data(),QLocale::system()));
```

This is the displayText() method in the base class (Delegado):

```
QString Delegado::displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const
{
    return locale.toString(value.toDouble(),'f',2);
}
```

And this is the paint() method in the derived class (Delegado2)

```
void Delegado2::paint( QPainter *painter,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(QColor(255,240,170));
        painter->setBrush(QColor(255,240,170));
        painter->drawRect(option.rect);
        painter->setPen(Qt::magenta);
        painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignCenter|Qt::AlignRight, displayText(index.data(),QLocale::system()));
        painter->restore();
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```